# Filter google spreadsheet by date and time

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following data in Google Spreadsheet:

```
| Users |                Timestamp |
|     1 | 2019-09-19T09:28:00.598Z |
|     2 | 2019-09-20T09:28:00.598Z |
|     3 | 2019-09-21T09:28:00.598Z |
|     4 | 2019-09-22T09:28:00.598Z |
|     5 | 2019-09-23T09:28:00.598Z |
```

How can I make a Charts filter for it? Apparently Charts.newNumberRangeFilter does not work with dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use [DateRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#daterangefilter) instead

Sample:

```
var myDateRangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'DateRangeFilter',
                'containerId': 'chartFilter',
                'options': {
                    'filterColumnLabel': 'Date',
                    'ui': {
                       format: {
                        pattern: 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'
                        },
                       step: 'day'
          }
       }
   })
```